# Where does this algorithm to find the upper triangular form of a matrix come from and where can I read more about it?

Tags: matrices, algorithms, computational-mathematics, triangularization

I am taking a course in *Computational Mathematics*. During one of my recent lectures about different algorithms when dealing with matrices, the following what they call "block-algorithm" is a good and decently fast way of generating the *upper triangular form* of a matrix. Sadly the algorithm was not presented in any adequately detailed way and as such I've been "left hanging". I've tried to Google it up but am having a real hard time finding any good resources about this algorithm, I don't even know it's name (was never presented and "block algorithm" doesn't yield much good).

So here I am, **asking you if you know what this algorithm is all about and if you have any solid resources to learn more about it?** What would be absolutely *AMAZING* would be to have some kind of visualizer of it where one can step through the code and see in real time what is going on.

```
/* reduce matrix A to upper triangular form */
void eliminate(double **A, int N, int B)
{
    int i, j, k, I, J;
    /* size of block is (M*M) */
    int M = N / B;
    /* for all block rows */
    for (I = 0; I < B; I++)
    {
        /* for all block columns */
        for (J = 0; J < B; J++)
        {
            /* loop over pivot elements */
            for (k = 0; k <= Min((I + 1) * M - 1, (J + 1) * M - 1); k++)
            {
                /* if pivot element within block */
                if (k >= I * M && k <= (I + 1) * M - 1)
                {
                    /* perform calculations on pivot */
                    for (j = Max(k + 1, J * M); j <= (J + 1) * M - 1; j++)
                    {
                        A[k][j] = A[k][j] / A[k][k];
                    }
                    /* if last element in row */
                    if (j == N)
                        A[k][k] = 1.0;
                }
                /* for all rows below pivot row within block */
                for (i = Max(k + 1, I * M); i <= (I + 1) * M - 1; i++)
                {
                    /* for all elements in row within block */
                    for (j = Max(k + 1, J * M); j <= (J + 1) * M - 1; j++)
                    {
                        A[i][j] = A[i][j] - A[i][k] * A[k][j];
                    }
                    /* if last element in row */
                    if (j == N)
                        A[i][k] = 0.0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
} /* end eliminate */
```

One other algorithm that was presented was the following that is a lot less complicated and easier to visualize. It is though not as performant as the top one.

````
/* reduce matrix A to upper triangular form */
void eliminate (double **A, int N) {
    int i, j, k;
    /* loop over all diagonal (pivot) elements */
    for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        /* for all elements in pivot row and right of pivot element */
        for (j = k + 1; j < N; j++) {
            /* divide by pivot element */
            A[k][j] = A[k][j] / A[k][k];
        }

        /* set pivot element to 1.0 */
        A[k][k] = 1.0;

        /* for all elements below pivot row and right of pivot column */
        for (i = k + 1; i < N; i++) {
                for (j = k + 1; j < N; j++) {
                    A[i][j] = A[i][j] - A[i][k] * A[k][j];
                }
                A[i][k] = 0.0;
        }
    } /* end pivot loop */
} /* end eliminate */
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is really just performing fairly standard row-reduction, but in a way that (a) allows the calculations to happen "in place" (i.e. by altering the values in the array, rather than creating a new array at each step), and (b) groups calculations within loops in a way that winds up being efficient (rather than needing to iterate back and forth).

The "blocking" involves dividing the (presumably $N \times N$) matrix into $B$ parts horizontally and vertically, giving $B \times B$ total blocks. If we ignore the blocking (equivalent to setting $B = 1$), the algorithm does the following:

- For each row $k$ in the matrix:

  - Set $A_{k,\cdot} := A_{k,\cdot} / A_{k,k}$
  - i.e. scale row $k$ so that its leading term is 1
  - For each row $i > k$ below row $k$:

    - Set $A_{i,\cdot} := A_{i,\cdot} - A_{i,k} \times A_{k,\cdot}$
    - i.e. row-reduce row $i$ by row $k$ to eliminate the value in the $k$-th column

The blocking version just does this operation within blocks - it loops over each row of blocks, and within that row it loops over each column of blocks. It does this by "forgetting" to set $A_{k,k}$ to 1 and $A_{i,k}$ to 0 until it's in the last column of blocks, so that the coefficients are still present.

[image: A square divided into 4 partitions labelled B11, B12, B21, B22 in reading order, with a grey diagonal line going from top-left to bottom right.]

This diagram shows how the algorithm processes a matrix if $B = 2$:

1. It diagonalises $B_{1,1}$, but doesn't set the diagonal elements to 1 yet.
2. It scales $B_{1,2}$ and sets the diagonal elements in $B_{1,1}$ to 1.
3. It row-reduces $B_{2,1}$ by each row in $B_{1,1}$, making use of the knowledge that $B_{1,1}$ is now upper triangular to skip all of its lower-left zeros, saving a few calculations.
4. Finally, it diagonalises $B_{2,2}$.

Overall, it will be taking something like $O(B^2 (N/B)^3)$ operations to do everything, and it should mean that there's a value of $B$ the optimises the number of operations (I'm guessing it's somewhere around $B \sim \sqrt{N}$).

I will note that if I'm reading it right the algorithm assumes that the matrix is invertible and has a non-zero entry in $A_{1,1}$, otherwise you're going to get some dumb behaviour, but it would be pretty easy to adjust to cover those cases.